# When clicking outside nav, the nav should close (but does not)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I have following `nav` file. And a `contextnav` file. In my `nav` file, I added code to make any click outside the `nav` close the `nav`. This does not work, actually nothing happens. How to make the `nav` that is opened, gets closed when you click outside that `nav`. Where is my mistake? Files are `tsx`

`nav` file

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function Nav() {
  const { nav, setNav } = useNavContext();
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = (event: { target: any }) => {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target as Node)) {
        setNav(true);
      }
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClick, true);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClick, true);
      };
    };
  }, [ref, setNav]);
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <div
        className={` bg-blue-500 ${ nav ? "w-[0vw]" : "w-[50vw"} `}
      >
      Here my nav code
      </div>
```

`contextnav` file

```
"use client";
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const NavContext = createContext<{ nav: boolean; setNav: Function }>({
  nav: false,
  setNav: () => {},
});
export default function NavContextProvider({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const [nav, setNav] = useState(true);
  return (
    <NavContext.Provider value={{ nav, setNav }}>
      {children}
    </NavContext.Provider>
  );
}
export function useNavContext() {
  return useContext(NavContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the [useClickAway](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/HEAD/docs/useClickAway.md) hook from [react-use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use)

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {useClickAway} from 'react-use';

export default function Nav() {
  const { nav, setNav } = useNavContext();
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

 useClickAway(ref, () => {
    setNav(false);
  });

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <div
        className={` bg-blue-500 ${ nav ? "w-[0vw]" : "w-[50vw"} `}
      >
        Here my nav code
      </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: but whats wrong with my code? I want my code to work and to learn

Comment: You have nav state to true. Shouldn’t it be false?